# Successor of a regular cardinal does not reflect stationary sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal. Then supposedly $\kappa^+$ does not reflect stationary sets. That is to say, there exists a stationary set $S\subseteq\kappa^+$ such that for every $\alpha<\kappa^+$ of uncountable cofinality, $S\cap\alpha$ is not stationary in $\alpha$. I'm not sure why this is true. My guess would be to let
$$S=\{\alpha<\kappa^+ : \operatorname{cf}(\alpha)=\kappa\}$$
but I'm not sure if this stationary set works or how to show it does work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited because my previous example did not suffice:

Let $\alpha<\kappa^+$ have uncountable cofinality. I'll build a club $C$ of order type $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ consisting only of members of cofinality less than $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$. If $A=\{a_{\alpha}\}$ is any $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$-sequence with supremum $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$, then I will let $C$ be the club in $\alpha$ which is the sequence $\{a_{\alpha}\}$, but adding $1$ to every successor ordinal in $A$. Then your set $S$ does not reflect at $\alpha$. This should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I fixed that typo. However, I'm not so sure the C you constructed works. Indeed, $C=\alpha$ since if $\beta<\alpha$, then $\operatorname{cf}(\beta)\leq\beta<\alpha$. But of course $\alpha$ intersects $S$ for $\alpha>\kappa$.

Comment: Silly typo on my part. I've edited the post.

Comment: I see, I see. While $C=\{\beta<\alpha : \operatorname{cf}(\beta)<\kappa\}$ is certainly disjoint from $S$, I don't believe this is a club. For example, if $\alpha>\kappa$, then $\sup(C\cap\kappa)=\kappa$, but $\kappa\notin C$.

Comment: @Anon You are correct. I have edited my answer to give a different construction which does the job. I'm not sure the protocol when an answer is given that is just incorrect, so I hope it was okay to just edit.

Comment: I think it's fine to just edit your answer. However, I'm still not convinced that this $C$ is a club or that it's disjoint from $S$. What if $\alpha=\kappa\cdot\kappa$ (ordinal mutliplication) so $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)=\kappa$ and the sequence happens to be $a_\xi=\kappa\cdot\xi$ for $\xi<\kappa$?

Comment: Actually I see what you mean. When you say "adding 1 to every successor ordinal in $A$" you mean something which is a successor in the ordering on $A$. Every element of $A$ of cofinality $\kappa$ must be of this form. Secondly, $C$ is not closed a priori, but we can force it to be. Thanks!

Comment: @Anon That's exactly it! I should have put in those details but I'm glad it worked out.

Comment: Much simpler argument, pick any cofinal club of minimal order type, and then look at its limit points.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you, Asaf. Much easier. I should have come up with that.

Comment: Oh, when I was a masters students I've had the exact same approach as you, and had more experienced researchers make similar comments to me. It's part of the deal. Feel free to edit that into your answer, there's little point in me posting another one.